# Xml deserializer not working

Tags: c#, xml, servicestack, deserialization

Below is my output object class -

```
 [XmlRoot("OutputParameters")]
 public class OutputParameters
 {
    [XmlElement(ElementName="X_INFO",Order=1)]
    public Info X_Info { get; set; }
 }
public class Info{   

 }
```

Xml deserializer is working if I use _ in **X_Info**. But if I remove this _ it will not de serialize this property. I have used same XMLElement attribute in both case. Can anyone tell, what is problem with removing _from Property name?

below is XML

```
   <OutputParameters xmlns:client="http://xmlns.oracle.com/Merge/SearchPartyOrPersonCDH/SearchPartyOrPersonCDHBPELProcess" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:plnk="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wsbpel/2.0/plnktype" xmlns:ns0="http://xmlns.oracle.com/pcbpel/adapter/db/sp/SearchCDHInfo" xmlns="http://xmlns.oracle.com/pcbpel/adapter/db/sp/SearchCDHInfo">
<ns0:X_INFO>
 </ns0:X_INFO>
</OutputParameters>
```

Comment: Show what xml are you trying to deserialize and the result of deserialization

Comment: Can you post a [mcve], that attempts to deserialize the xml?

Comment: I am using Service stack ServiceClient to get xml data.and using default deserialiser provided by that client.

Comment: Does changing the `XmlElementAttribute.Namespace` property to `"ns0"` remedy the problem?

Comment: @Adwaenyth -same issue..I tried ns0 still same issue,.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Used dataContract with Datamember worked fine for xml de serialisation.